# Count in mongoDB

Tags: mongodb-query

I have something like this for every user in mongoDB:

```
{
    "id" : 1234,
    "name" : "Mr. Someone",
    "userdata" : {
        "living" : {
            "city" : "Somecity",
            "address" : "Main Street 10.",
            "zip" : "1023"
        },
        "interest" : "Cars"
}
```

I'm trying to find a way to count how many subscribers live in Somecity.

My best guess was the following:

```
db.users.count({userdata:{living:{city:"Somecity"}}}
```

But the result was 0.

How can I properly count "rows" by a given value in mongoDB?

I'm using mongoDB's documentation (for example: http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/sql-comparison/) but could not resolve my problem yet.

I'm using mongoDB trough shell.

Comment: What result gives you the same query without the count (db.users.find({userdata:{living:{city:"Somecity"}}})? Are you sure it gives you the results you want to retrieve?. I know it shoulds, but....

Comment: Find() gives also nothing in return. But if I understand you correctly, my syntax should be fine? The problem may be somewhere else?

Comment: Yes, the syntax seems valid. Try db.users.find({}) and see if it returns all of your records

Answer (score 0):

I think I have found the sollution to my problem:

```
db.users.count({"userdata.living.city":"Somecity"})
```

This "dotting" method allowed me to search for only one value in the array, while the method I tried first wanted to find an exact match.

Further reading: http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/elemMatch/

Quote:

> Since the $elemMatch only specifies a single condition, the $elemMatch
>   expression is not necessary, and instead you can use the following
>   query:
>
> db.survey.find(    { "results.product": "xyz" } )